# why does my python code using opencv is giving typeerror?

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, motion-detection

this is my code

```
import cv2
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector 

cap=cv2.VideoCapture('Video (1).mp4') 

detector=PoseDetector() 

posList = []
while True: # This line starts an infinite loop. The code inside this loop will continue to run until it encounters a break statement or the program is terminated manually.

    success, img = cap.read() 

    img = detector.findPose(img) 

   lmList,bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img) 
    
    
    if bboxInfo:
        lmString = ''
        for lm in lmList:
            # print(lm)
            lmString += f'{lm[1]},{img.shape[0]-lm[2]},{lm[3]}'
        posList.append(lmString)
    
    print(posList)
            # num_points = len(lmList)
            # print("Number of Points Detected:", num_points)


    cv2.imshow("Image",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

this is the error:

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\py_projects\motionDetector\motionCap.py", line 22, in <module>
    lmString += f'{lm[1]},{img.shape[0]-lm[2]},{lm[3]}'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

the should display the changing position of the landmarks on the video

Comment: `lmList` is a 3-dimensional list. So `lm[2]` is a list, not a number, and you can't subtract it from a number.

Answer (score 0):

- In this line `lmString += f'{lm[1]},{img.shape[0]-lm[2]},{lm[3]}'`, you are rying to subtract a list from an integer which causes a `TypeError`.
- you need to ensure that `lm[2]` is an integer before performing the subtraction.
- By accessing `lm[2][0]`, you're retrieving the first element of the `lm[2]` list, which should be an `integer`.

```py
lmString += f'{lm[1]},{img.shape[0]-lm[2][0]},{lm[3]}'
```